# VueJS format ternary expression

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using VueJS and it has expression like below:

```
{{ item.recommendation ? "PS4" : "Xbox" }}
```

How can I style "PS4" into red color or "Xbox" into blue color in the expression?  In another words, how to include CSS style into the expression.

Comment: use class bind .. `:class="sitem.recommendation ? 'is-primary' : 'is-info' "`

Comment: @AbdullahAlNoor, yes got it thanks, you can answer and I will mark it correct...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**you can try like this way**

```
 :class="sitem.recommendation ? 'is-primary' : 'is-info' "
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind a class:

```
:class="condition ? 'classA' : 'classB'"
```

Or you can bind a style:

```
:style="condition ? {color: 'red'} : {color: 'blue'}"
```

[reference](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html)